# array of pointers to member functions: make it work

Tags: c++, arrays, class, function, pointers

In the following code I am getting the error:

`a value of type (double*)(const double& arg) const cannot be assigned to an entity of type pt2calculateA`

Any suggestions on how to make it work?

```
class myClass {
    private:

    typedef double (*pt2calculateA)(double);

    pt2calculateA calculateA[2];

public:

    myClass () {
        calculateA[0] = &calculateA1; //->error
        calculateA[1] = &calculateA2; //->error
    }

    double calculateA1(const double& arg) const {
            ...
    }

    double calculateA2(const double& arg) const {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`myClass::calculateA1()` **is not a function**; rather, it is a **member function**. So the types are naturally not compatible.

The type of `&myClass::calculcateA1` is `double (myClass::*)(const double &) const`, which is a pointer-to-member-function (PTFM). Note that you can only use a PTMF together with a pointer to an object instance (i.e. a `myClass*`).

If you change your typedef, you could at least store the pointers correctly:

```
typedef double (myClass::*pt2calculateA)(const double &) const;
```

You'll have to say `&myClass::calculateA1`, etc., to take the address.

In C++11, you can initialize the array in the initializer list:

```
myClass() : calculateA{&myClass::calculateA1, &myClass::calculateA2} { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class myClass {
    private:

    typedef double (myClass::*pt2calculateA)(const double&) const;

    pt2calculateA calculateA[2];

public:

    myClass () {
        calculateA[0] = &myClass::calculateA1;
        calculateA[1] = &myClass::calculateA2;
    }

    double calculateA1(const double& arg) const {
        //    ...
    }

    double calculateA2(const double& arg) const {
        //  ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not only the parameter type differs between the typedef and the actual functions, but also one is a function pointer while the other is a member function pointer. `myClass::calculateA1` has type `double (myClass::*)(const double& arg) const`.

Answer (score 0):

`pt2calculateA` is declared as a pointer-to-function, not a pointer-to-member-function.

see [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html)